# How to create and start an infinite background script in php?

Tags: php, background, jobs

I want to create a PHP script that will run non stop and execute some instructions every minute/hour (according to my need). It should never die.

How should I proceed to this one? How do I start the script itself?

What Iv'e done so far is created an infinite for loop and checking the time and if it's a new minute then calling my function. But when I call the link, it shows my browser is busy.

I want the script to run on Google Compute Engine without any need to call the URL from a second computer. I want something like android foreground service but for PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron job is the answer.

Cron is basically a job scheduling daemon. It runs in the background and is executed automatically. You can set it to run at any time that you wish to. This nature of cron makes it useful for automating tasks.
A cron job, is a task which we carry out with the help of a cron.

So if you run a php script with the help of a cron, it'll run on the background. We don't need to run any infinite loops in the script. You can also set a cron job to run at specific time. How it is run and when it is run is totally upto how you configure the cron job. For that you have to edit the crontab file. A cron tab file is a text file containing a list of commands meant to be run at specified times and the commands in the crontab file along with their run times are checked by the cron daemon, which executes them in the system background.

Now, to create or edit entries in your own cron tab file:

> $ crontab -e

Add an entry in the crontab file. One thing you have to remember is, for executing php scripts, use the php executable and call the php script from your crontab as shown in the example below

> */2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/project/cron-file.php

[This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-ubuntu-1804) reference might be helpful to you.

Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

For Unix-system, best practice for such tasks is using Cron: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Not only for PHP, but any periodical tasks.

Comment: Will it make my terminal window busy? Can I close my terminal window after scheduling the job?

Comment: @Arghadip cron will perform tasks in backgroud, you can close your terminal. It will work as long as your server is up.